# Network Trash showing on my desktop

Tags: networking, trash

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS on my company PC. After installing some software to test out I decided to uninstall them.

The problem I have is that every time I start my computer my trash bin shows as full and it contains files and folders that don't belong to me. If I start the PC with the network cable unplugged it will show the empty trash bin. Reconnecting the network will "return" this trash into my bin after a few hours. Trying to empty from the desktop, nautilus or the command prompt does not work. The desktop will show as busy trying to delete (it will time-out eventually) and the command prompt shows the folder as empty. Nautilus confirms my "local" trash folder is empty.

Any Ideas on where to look to stop this behaviour? I want to keep my trash local and keep my hard drive from running most of the time (which is a side effect). If this was a Windows PC I would think it is a virus. To me it seems like it scans the network and puts other PCs' trash in my bin. BTW, my company's IT guy doesn't want to touch it because "I" messed it up.

Comment: Can u post the name of folders and files in the trash bin

Comment: Also can u post the command you used to empty the trash from terminal

Comment: There is an "untitled folder" and several JPG files as well as a couple of Powerpoint presentations (I don't use PP) and 2 Thumbs.db files.  The jpgs have consecutive time stamps with a minute difference (if that matters)

Comment: hmmm This is interesting. I have no clue how this might be happening

Comment: Could you [edit] the output of `mount` onto your question please? I suspect this has something to do with how the network share works but still, pretty weird!

Comment: do you have any network drives mounted to your system